# why WCF service don't return list<>?

Tags: wcf

When i add/edit the service client, if i click on the "Advanced ..." button i will see an option allowing me to choose the collection type for my client proxy . The default is System.Array. When I change to System.Collaction.Generic.List and click Add proxy create. But in my method return value i see type[] but not List, why? What i do wrong?
this is class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Asset
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal AssetId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you generate proxy class choise `List` instead `Array`

Comment: I choise List but metod return type[]

Comment: I regenerate proxy but this dont help